# Getting Information from POST data

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to create a plugin that takes the POST data from an order and emails it to the end user. Which property should I use to do this? I've already tried to use `getContent()` and `getContentFromPost()`.

So for example if I have

```
         <input type="text" name="dataName" value="">
```

And in my plugin I'm trying to get the value of "dataName" which property should I use?

Answer (score 5):

[HttpRequestService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService)'s [getPost](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getPost-detail) is what you're looking for:

```
$value = craft()->request->getPost('dataName');
```

Comment: Or you can get all the POST data in one go with

`$vars = craft()->request->getPost();`

Comment: You may also want to look at https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceMailer for some stuff to get you started in this area...

Answer (score 2):

In CraftCMS 3.x `craft.app.request.getBodyParam('dataName')`